# C OMP for loop in parallel region. Not work-shared

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a function that I want to parallelize. This is the serial version.

```
void parallelCSC_SpMV(float *x, float *b)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < numcols; i++)
    {
        for(j = colptrs[i] - 1; j < colptrs[i+1] - 1; j++)
        {
            b[irem[j] - 1] += xrem[j]*x[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I figured a decent way to do this was to  have each thread write to a private copy of the b array (which does not need to be a protected critical section because its a private copy), after the thread is done, it will then copy its results to the actual b array. Here is my code.

```
void parallelCSC_SpMV(float *x, float *b)
{
    int i, j, k;
    #pragma omp parallel private(i, j, k)
    {
        float* b_local = (float*)malloc(sizeof(b));       
     
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for(i = 0; i < numcols; i++)
        {
            for(j = colptrs[i] - 1; j < colptrs[i+1] - 1; j++)
            {
                float current_add = xrem[j]*x[i];
                int index = irem[j] - 1;
                b_local[index] += current_add;
            }
        }
        
        for (k = 0; k < sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]); k++)
        {
            // Separate question: Is this if statement allowed?
            //if (b_local[k] == 0) { continue; }
            #pragma omp atomic
            b[k] += b_local[k];
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get a segmentation fault as a result of the second for loop. I do not need to a `"#pragma omp for"` on that loop because I want each thread to execute it fully. If I comment out the content inside the for loop, no segmentation fault. I am not sure what the issue would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probabily trying to access an out of range position in the dynamic array b_local.

See that `sizeof(b)` will return the size in bytes of `float*` (size of a float pointer).

If you want to know the size of the array that you are passing to the function, i would suggest you add it to the parameters of the function.

```
void parallelCSC_SpMV(float *x, float *b, int b_size){
...
    float* b_local = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*b_size); 
...
}
```

And, if the size of `colptrs` is `numcols`  i would be careful with `colptrs[i+1]`, since when `i=numcols-1` will have another out of range problem.

Comment: Apparently my c is pretty rusty lol. This brought back a bit of recollection with how some of these things work! Thanks!

Comment: In all of these answers, b_local is uninitialised, yet you are adding to it. You need to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

First, as pointed out by [Jim Cownie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1900441/jim-cownie):

> In all of these answers, b_local is uninitialised, yet you are adding
> to it. You need to use calloc instead of malloc

Just to add to the accepted answer, I thing you can try the following approach to avoid calling `malloc` in parallel, and also the overhead of calling `#pragma omp atomic`.

```
void parallelCSC_SpMV(float *x, float *b, int b_size, int num_threads) {
    
    float* b_local[num_threads];
    for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) 
       b_local[i] = calloc(b_size, sizeof(float));
    
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_threads)
    { 
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp for
        for(int i = 0; i < numcols; i++){ 
            for(int j = colptrs[i] - 1; j < colptrs[i+1] - 1; j++){
               float current_add = xrem[j]*x[i];
               int index = irem[j] - 1;
               b_local[tid][index] += current_add;
           }
       }
    }   
    for(int id = 0; id < num_threads; id++)
    {   
        #pragma omp for simd
        for (int k = 0; k < b_size; k++)
        {    
             b[k] += b_local[id][k];
        }
        free(b_local[id]);
    }
}
```

I have not tested the performance of this, so please feel free to do so and provide feedback.

You can further optimize by instead of creating a `local_b` for the master thread just reused the original `b`, as follows:

```
void parallelCSC_SpMV(float *x, float *b, int b_size, int num_threads) {
    
    float* b_local[num_threads-1];
    for(int i = 0; i < num_threads-1; i++) 
       b_local[i] = calloc(b_size, sizeof(float));
    
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_threads)
    { 
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        float *thread_b = (tid == 0) ? b : b_local[tid-1];
        #pragma omp for
        for(int i = 0; i < numcols; i++){ 
            for(int j = colptrs[i] - 1; j < colptrs[i+1] - 1; j++){
               float current_add = xrem[j]*x[i];
               int index = irem[j] - 1;
               thread_b[index] += current_add;
           }
       }
    }   
    
    for(int id = 0; id < num_threads-1; id++)
    {   
        #pragma omp for simd
        for (int k = 0; k < b_size; k++)
        {    
             b[k] += b_local[id][k];
        }
        free(b_local[id]);
    }
}
```